# Is it possible to share a web application in a LAN network

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, mysql, lan, intranet

I was thinking if it would be possible to have a computer, which would have Apache, Mysql, PHP etc on it and host a web application while it is connected via a LAN network to, let's say, five-six other computers, which will act like clients, while the computer hosting the application would be a hosting server and a client at the same time. Can you point out any link on how to built such a network, or would it be just the same as making a LAN and then installing the required hosting components to a computer I decide to make the host. Moreover, I think it can be done with an intranet, but that is kinda expensive.

Comment: Confused as to what you want to do. You want multiple machines to host a web application?

Comment: No, just one machine which will be the host and a client at the same time, while other machines connected to this machine (through LAN) will act as clients. Is it possible?

Comment: yea you just need to create a web server. You can lock it down so only certain ip ranges or certain ips can connect to there as well. Not sure what OS you are using, but using linux for web hosting is super easy. Then you can add that computer to the hosts file so it's easier to access or setup a DNS server and add a record for that. I'm not sure what exactly you are working with, so I can't give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its super easy, Install XAMPP (Most widely used Development Environment) , After installing XAMPP , it will automatically configure your computer to use localhost on port 80, next In your windows firewall allow port 80 or program apache to be accessed from other computers from network, and at last, find your computers ip address, there are several ways but the most convinient is to go to command (start->run->cmd) and type ipconfig, and it will show you your current ip address, use that ip address to access your webserver from other computers on the same network.

Isn't super easy?

Comment: If your computer is the Server (DHCP) than adding a entry in your HOST file will also do the favor :) Instead of remembering the IP , you 'll only need the domain name than!

Comment: I figured it out the way you explained to me. It was pretty straightforward. I'm choosing this as the best answer as it's the only one. Anyway, thanks to the other guys as well.

Comment: you are welcome :) I'm glad i helped you out!